# Fix HTML header and button tag not updating text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some code that updates a header tag and a button tag. However, when I use the method `.text();` it does not work. So I looked up the proper way to do it via other stack overflow questions, and I see basically the same thing. Everyone is telling me to use `.text()` or `.html()`. So I am really confused on why it is not working. I am not sure if it has anything to do with values already in the tag.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="contents">
  <div class="card text-center myCard">
    <div class="card-header"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ttBtn"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".eBtn").on(
                    "click",
                    function(event) {


                        event.preventDefault();

                        var href = $(this).attr('href');
                        console.log(href);

                        $.get(href, function(ary2, status) {
                            $("#displayAppName").val(ary2.appname);
                            $("#appcode").val(ary2.appcode);
                            $("#editStatus").val(ary2.status);




                            if (ary2.mapstatus == "" || ary2.mapstatus == null) {
                                mapBool = true;
                                $("#mapStatus").val("");
                                $("#createBtn").val('Create');
                                $('#modalCreateBtn').attr(
                                        'href',
                                        '/create?currentAppcode='
                                                + ary2.appcode
                                                + "&currentAcro="
                                                + ary2.acronym
                                                + "&currentAppname="
                                                + ary2.appname);








                                console.log("Card Create: " + $(".card-title").val());



                            } else {
                                $("#mapStatus").val("Mapped");
                                $("#createBtn").val('Edit');
                                $('#modalCreateBtn').attr(
                                        'href',
                                        '/edit?currentAppcode='
                                                + ary2.appcode
                                                + "&currentAcro="
                                                + ary2.acronym);

                                  mapBool = true;


                                console.log("Card Edit: " + $(".card-title").val());


                            }

                        });

                          console.log("Main Boolean : "  + this.mapBool)
                          console.log("Main Boolean : "  + mapBool)
                            if(mapBool){
                                 $(".card-title").text("Application Mapped!");
                                 $(".card-text").text("Continue to view application");
                                $(".ttBtn").text("New Mapping after");
                            }

                        $("#exampleModal").modal();


                    });
```

**jQuery Change HTML:**

```
  $(".card-title").text("Application Mapped!");
  $(".card-text").text("Continue to view application");
  $(".ttBtn").text("Continue");
```

Comment: Check the condition value `ary2.mapstatus == "" || ary2.mapstatus == null` `console.log()` helps a lot in debugging, maybe `ary2` variable is not empty string and is not null, also where did you put the javascript tag, try to move it to the bottom of the `<body>` tag or make sure that its in document.ready.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman So I did a test prior where I put the code in both conditions, and they still don't work.

Comment: Can you add the full HTML code? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: where is your  header tag ?

Comment: @Ma'mounothman So I can't put the full HTML code because it is sensitive and long. However, I made an update to the jQuery to add a Boolean and have that change the state. However, not that is not properly reading the Boolean. It always prints out false;

Answer (score 0):

Created variable `ary2`. Hope this help you.

```js
var ary2 = [];
if (ary2.mapstatus == "" || ary2.mapstatus == null) {
  $("#mapStatus").val("");
  $("#createBtn").val('Create');
  $('#modalCreateBtn').attr(
    'href',
    '/create?currentAppcode=' +
    ary2.code +
    "&currentAcro=" +
    ary2.acro +
    "&currentAppname=" +
    ary2.name);

  $(".card-title").text("Application Mapped!");
  $(".card-text").text("Continue to view application");
  $(".ttBtn").html("Continue");


} else {
  $("#mapStatus").val("Mapped");
  $("#createBtn").val('Edit');
  $('#modalCreateBtn').attr(
    'href',
    '/edit?currentAppcode=' +
    ary2.code +
    "&currentAcro=" +
    ary2.acro);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".card-title").text("Application Mapped!");
  $(".card-text").text("Continue to view application");
  $(".ttBtn").html("Continue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="card text-center myCard">
    <div class="card-header"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Application not mapped!</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Click the "New Tier" button to begin mapping.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ttBtn">New
        Mapping</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried the code and it still does not work for me. I tried using instead a Boolean in my above code that I just edited and it too still does not work. I tried adding the Boolean to just run when the value is changed to ```true```. Though the value always says false. I have no clue how to fix it.